# XML-Parse img src tag with Picasso

Tags: android, regex, xml, xml-parsing, pattern-matching

How could I parse (I use DOM parsing) an image from an URL, with Picasso, but it's already wrapped into content:encoded and then in CDATA, which I already parsed, but I could get it to load the image.

My XML looks like the following:

```
<item>
    <desc>
       txt txt txt txt <img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png"> txt txt
       <img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png"> ...
    </desc>
</item>
<item>
    <desc>
       txt txt txt txt <img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png"> txt txt
       <img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png"><img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png">
    </desc>
</item>
```

I just need to download it with Picasso.

Here's my DOMParser.java:

```
package net.biscani.parser;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class DOMParser {

    // Create a new RSS feed
    private RSSFeed feed = new RSSFeed();

    public RSSFeed parseXML(String feedURL) {

        // Create a new URL
        URL url = null;
        try {
            // Find the new URL from the given URL
            url = new URL(feedURL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // Throw an exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a new DocumentBuilder
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

            // Parse the XML
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            // Normalize the data
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // Get all <item> tags.
            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            // Get size of the list
            int length = list.getLength();

            // For all the items in the feed
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                // Create a new node of the first item
                Node currentNode = list.item(i);
                // Create a new RSS item
                RSSItem item = new RSSItem();

                // Get the child nodes of the first item
                NodeList nodeChild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                // Get size of the child list
                int cLength = nodeChild.getLength();

                // For all the children of a node
                for (int j = 1; j < cLength; j = j + 2) {
                    // Get the name of the child
                    String nodeName = nodeChild.item(j).getNodeName(), nodeString = null;
                    // If there is at least one child element
                    if(nodeChild.item(j).getFirstChild() != null){
                        // Set the string to be the value of the node
                        nodeString = nodeChild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    }
                    // If the string isn't null
                    if (nodeString != null) {
                        // Set the appropriate value
                        if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                            item.setTitle(nodeString);
                        } else if ("content:encoded".equals(nodeName)) {
                            item.setDescription(nodeString);
                        } else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {
                            item.setDate(nodeString.replace(" +0000", ""));
                        } else if ("author".equals(nodeName) || "dc:creator".equals(nodeName)) {
                            item.setAuthor(nodeString);
                        } else if ("link".equals(nodeName)){
                            item.setURL(nodeString);
                        } else if ("image".equals(nodeName)){
                            item.setThumb(nodeString);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Add the new item to the RSS feed
                feed.addItem(item);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return the feed
        return feed;
    }
}
```

And also my ListAdapter.java:

```
package net.biscani;

import net.biscani.R;
import net.biscani.parser.RSSFeed;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Create a new LayoutInflater
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    // Create a new RSSFeed
    private RSSFeed feed;

    public ListAdapter(Context c, RSSFeed rssFeed) {
        // Set the layout inflater
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // Set the RSS feed
        feed = rssFeed;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Set the total list item count
        return feed.getItemCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // Return the position
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // Return the position
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View listItem, ViewGroup parent) {
        // If a list item is null
        if (listItem == null) {
            // Inflate a list item
            listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list_item, null);
        }
        // Set the views in the layout
                ((TextView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
                // Bit of formatting for adding the author
                ((TextView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(feed.getItem(position).getDate());
                ((TextView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(Html.fromHtml(feed.getItem(position).getDescription()));
                ((TextView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.author)).setText(feed.getItem(position).getAuthor());
                // Return the new list item
        return listItem;
    }
}
```